# isolating unique sound from two otherwise identical audios

Tags: sound-design

I have two audios, one of which has an additional voice in it that I want to extract. I have tried noise reduction with the cleaner version as is suggested at https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/tutorial_vocal_removal_and_isolation.html. and I tried inverting the cleaner version as is suggested by [Isolate the difference between two mostly-identical audio tracks?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/23389/isolate-the-difference-between-two-mostly-identical-audio-tracks). Problem is, it seems that I can't exactly line up the two audios and I get this slightly off sounding copy. Is there a way to line up the two audios at the exact point of a common sound? I zoomed in as closely as I could and tried to eyeball it but it seems that I'm just a little off.

Comment: "can't exactly line up"... why? Because they're from different sources, different sample rates, or...? Basically this is one of those questions that crops up a lot & the answer is always 'if you can line it up you can do it. If you can't, you can't', certainly not in Audacity [read: for free]. 'identical' means just that, it doesn't mean 'a bit like the other one'.

Comment: I'm sure that it's the same sample rate, I'm just hoping to find a tool,method, or program I don't know about to line up the audios perfectly.

Comment: Line up the first really obvious beat point manually. Check further down the recording to see if it time-slips. If it does then you're going to have to time-stretch one of them until it matches. The chances of getting this to work perfectly if the 2 audio sources are different is pretty remote - you didn't answer that part of my first comment.

Comment: yeah I'm pretty sure it's from the same source and one is just composited over the other.

Comment: If they're identical, then what's preventing you lining them up accurately? If they absolutely will not line up, then by definition they are not identical.

Comment: Yeah i thought i just needed to line them up more precisely but I realize now that the files are not other wise identical as I thought. Mb, i feel stupid. thanks for your help!